# CKEditor and VideoEmbed plugin

Tags: plugins, configuration, ckeditor

Can anybody tell me how can I use embedMedia plugin in ckeditor? I am using drupal 6 and WYSIWYG editor. I have added the folder into plugin folder. And added a line on config.js,

> config.extraPlugins += (config.extraPlugins? ',MediaEmbed':
>   'MediaEmbed');

But I have not seen the option on my configuration. Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some one please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to your config.toolbar_XXX setting in order to have it appear.

Look in your config.js file for something like:

```
config.toolbar_XXX

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_XXX
```

The standard full toolbar config looks like this:

```
  config.toolbar_Full =
  [
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
           'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-

          ','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
  ];
```

You would need to add an entry for your plugin in the spot you want the button to appear. Check the plugin readme to see what the button should be called.

If you don't see this in your config.js file, you can add it there and insert the name of the button for the embedmedia plugin. It looks like the name of the button is "MediaEmbed", try adding it next to one of the current buttons (add 'MediaEmbed') and it should be visible in the toobar.

It might be helpful to take a look at the CKEditor docs to gain a better understanding of how the toolbar is customized:

[CKEditor Toolbar](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar)

Comment: Where is the location of the file

Comment: Where you add it depends on whether you are using the default configuration, a custom config, or are setting the toolbar contents when the CKEditor instance is being created. What are you doing?